# How to display a list of Strings with Handlebars.js

Tags: string, list, handlebars.js

I have a list of Strings that I want to display with Handlebars.js

So far it seems that this is not possible, although it seems absurd that this should be the case.

An example of a `product` object is:

```
"product": {
      "name": "top TP-209-NAV",
      "category": "Top",
      "brand": "Living Dolls",
      "description": "Fabric : Navy-white stretch cotton Long sleeves top (can be worn as dress)",
      "price": "23.0",
      "tags": [
        "Slips on",
        " stretch cotton",
        " long sleeves"
      ],
      "image1": {
        "src": "http://www.livingdolls-closet.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/T/P/TP-209-NAV-1-living-dolls-top_1.jpg",
        "ratio": 1.5
      }
    },
```

I want to iterate through and display the items in the `tags` list.

When I do something like this I can see the appropriate number of commas which indicates that the list is being iterated through, however I can't work out how to display the actual tag item.

```
{{#product.tags}}<a href="">{{val}}</a>,  {{/product.tags}}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I just had to use the `each` helper ..

```
{{#each product.tags}}<a href="">{{this}}</a>, {{/each}}
```

Comment: You can avoid having a comma after the last tag: {{#unless @last}}, {{/unless}}